# STM32 - Configure Output Compare Registers on the Fly

Tags: stm32, pwm, timer, interrupts, trigger

since this is my first, feel free to give newbie a feedback :)

I have a following setup with my STM32 Nucleo (simplified, ignore the HW behind):

a) one input signal acquisition (Square wave, consider it PWM)

b) one output signal (consider short pulses)

My goal is to read the signal a) and determine the frequency of the input PWM. Then on the rising edge of the signal a) I want to wait a calibratable amount of time (clock cycles) and then trigger short pulse with a calibratable width.

I have already done the first part (waiting for rising edge, estimating the frequency) by using Input Compare approach of TIM.
However I am a little bit stuck with a concept, how to manipulate Output Compare registers after specific time elapsed.

What would be most appropriate result? Triggering some kind of "update function" on every input rising edge, where this "update function" takes the current counter value of output compare register and "extend it" with predefined delay (mentioned above).

Would that be neat and clean approach?

Thank you for responses!

p.s. I have read about the "one pulse" option in STM32, but since the rising edges are occurring cyclically (with some jitter), I am thinking if I could use running counter with output compare runtime modification for my application.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking.  People update the duration (count) setting of output compare registers all the time, after initially configuring the operating mode.  You can also of course re-configure the entire output compare mode via a HAL function, though that will take longer.  It's not uncommon to see the pragmatic "abstraction violation" of using a HAL function to set something up, but then see that a PID control loop or similar *directly* writes the relevant timer OCR registers, rather than even call a HAL value update routine, as the loop needs to be tightly efficient.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for comment. I wanted opinions, possible drawbacks and blocking points.
I am aware that the update of output compare registers can be done, however as far as I know, the actual update will be done at the end of the period. That is when the config from shadow registers is shifter into compare registers. Is that correct?

Comment: There is an update generation register that controls whether the Output Compare uses whatever value is in the compare register, or whether it shadow buffers the compare register (makes a copy of the register at the beginning of the cycle and uses the value for current cycle allowing the register to be written to in advance for the next cycle).